# assigning variables in terraform name tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

my stack needs around 20 - 30 EC2 instances. I have a bunch of common tags that i define using the locals tag and then define a "Name" tag specific to each instance. The Name tag has some generic parts and some specific parts. is there a way to generalize the generic parts of the name tag ? I tried something like this where i defined a local variable for the instance_prefix, but terraform takes the it as "local.instnace_prefix" instead of the actual variable.

```
tags = merge(
local.common_tags,
{Name        = "local.instance_prefix-X-DB-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"})
```

this is how i run it currently

```
tags = merge(
local.common_tags,
{Name        = "PHL-STAGE01-X-DB-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"})
```

this is becoming tedious as the DC name (PHL) and env Name (Stage01) has to be updated for new builds and versions, so i want to have them as variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> terraform takes the it as "local.instnace_prefix" instead of the actual variable

This is because you are not resolving it in your string. It should be:

```
"${local.instance_prefix}-X-DB-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}"})
```

Also you have one extra `})` at the end for some reason.

Comment: Thanks that helped. Also is there a way to use sometime similar to do in the resource parameter? For example i use -- resource "aws_instance" "temp" --- can i do something like -- resource "aws_instance" ""${local.instance_prefix}-X-DB-${format("%02d", count.index + 1)}""